# Accessing Node element in xml using Xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm uploading xml file and accessing values in a php class. Everything is going smooth but when i try to access $middle_of_month value I have a debug error called

> "Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()"

Here's how xml looks like

```
...
<Fdr>
  <MiddleOfMonth>
      <Data Value="0" MonthNumber="1" />
      ...
```

I get the other tags correct I verified with debug.

```
$fdr             = $key->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_FDR);
$middle_of_month = $fdr->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_MIDDLE_OF_MONTH);
```

I have the error in $middle_of_month line. I debugged like 2 hours and still couldn't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Edit :

```
tag_constants::TAG_FDR -> Fdr
tag_constants::TAG_MIDDLE_OF_MONTH ->MiddleOfMonth
```

Edit 2 :

```
$middle_of_month = $fdr->item(0)->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_MIDDLE_OF_MONTH);
```

seems to solve the problem

Comment: should TAG_MIDDLE_OF_MONTH ->MiddleOfMont be TAG_MIDDLE_OF_MONTH ->MiddleOfMonth? May be you just mistyped?

Comment: Sorry, i mistyped here, in code it's correct. I editted here

Comment: And I added a control to see if $fdr is null or not and it's not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList`, and as the error implies, `NodeList`s do not in turn have this method (only `Element`s and `Document`s do).

You will need to pick an item from `$fdr` to run `getElementsByTagName()` on; perhaps like:

```
$fdr->item(0)->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_MIDDLE_OF_MONTH);
```